# Loading Video as blob stopped working on Safari Mobile iOS 17.0.2

Tags: video, mobile, safari, blob

I am trying to load a video as blob.
Code example below recently stopped working on Safari Mobile (iOS 17.0.2).
The example works on a desktop browser. Is this a bug in Safari Mobile?

```
async loadVideo  () {
    let url = require('@/assets/[VIDEO_FILE].mp4');
    const res = await fetch (url);
    const blob = await res.blob();
    document.getElementById('myVideo').src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
},
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does anyone have same experience?